# Is it true that Machine Learning is basically the study of Pattern recognition along with Optimization?

Tags: machine-learning

I study Pattern Recognition (Classification, Clustering, NeuralNet, Decision tree, and so on. But, excluding textual analysis), and Optimization (study of computational complexity, and trade off of computation and complexity of the target hypotheses, genetic algorithm, and so on) in my university.

If somewhere else somebody studies "Machine Learning", can I assume that they are actually studying Pattern Recognition + Optimization?

That is, is machine learning the study of pattern recognition along with optimization?

Comment: In your context does pattern recognition cover aspects such as semantics, textual analysis and the study of un- or semi-organized databases? And what does optimization mean? Is that the study of computational complexity, or perhaps even the trade off of computation  and complexity of the target hypotheses?

Comment: @SvanBalen, `Is that the study of computational complexity, or perhaps even the trade off of computation and complexity of the target hypotheses? ` -- yes.

Comment: @SvanBalen, `In your context does pattern recognition cover aspects such as semantics, textual analysis and the study of un- or semi-organized databases?` -- What I am studying in my Pattern Recognition course are: Classification, Clustering, NeuralNet, Decision tree, and so on. It excludes: textual analysis.

Comment: I'd say you would have a pretty good foundation then.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe? As Wikipedia says:

> The terms pattern recognition, machine learning, data mining and
>   knowledge discovery in databases (KDD) are hard to separate, as they
>   largely overlap in their scope.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition

Answer (score 0):

Machine Learning at its core is unsupervised learning. Its about making sense of unknown data. Unsupervised learning cropped up because, essentially many real world problems always have some priors associated with them.

At its core, data mining is about determining making sense of data. Simple data (2D) can be plotted, but what about 10,000 dimensions (sure there are means there these days but they themselves have their cons)? How would you go about it? You dont have any labels, someone just gave you a million point dataset and asked you to give them a report, what do you do then?  Would you pick up each sample and manually look at the values or would you like to use a tried and tested solution of partitioning it somehow and then looking at the classes? In a way you could say that unsupervised learning, although being the core, has these days become a pre-processor for its supervised counterpart.